# Can't update a UIImageView properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, sdwebimage

I call this method in my ViewController, which contains a UIScrollView, when the user taps a button.

```
-(void) updateView:(NSURL *) urlPicture{
      UIImageView *imageNews = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,200)];
    imageNews.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [imageNews setImageWithURL:urlPicture];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageNews];
}
```

It seems to work fine, but when I got a strange behavior.
It doesn't clear the previous image to put the new one.
E.g: if the first image is 300x200 and the second one is 200x200 I still can see the sides of the first one when the app download the second.

I would like to know how to clear the previous image before download the second.
I already try `imageNews.image = nil`; but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to remove old view from scrollView. You can edit your code as mentioned below

```
#define IMAGE_VIEW_TAG     1001
-(void) updateView:(NSURL *) urlPicture{
    UIView *oldView = [self.scrollView viewWithTag:IMAGE_VIEW_TAG];
    if(oldView)
        [oldView removeFromSuperView]
    UIImageView *imageNews = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,200)];
    imageNews.tag = IMAGE_VIEW_TAG;
    imageNews.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [imageNews setImageWithURL:urlPicture];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageNews];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not really sure what your application does , 
but seems like you need to have only 1 image 
so I would suggest you to remove the previous image.

There are 2 ways to do so:

1) you could use your image as property and simply call `[_imageNews removeFromSuperView];`

2) you can iterate through your `self.scrollView`'s sub views and remove it from there.

Comment: I have a Array with URLs and when the user click "Next" it shows the next picture. Something like that. I think the problem is that this method doesn't actually do what I want. I want to "destroy" the UIViewController and call it again with other parameters. Something like destroy and create Fragments in Android. There is a way to do that?

Comment: Better just do what I suggested or the answer bellow is actually did it for you which is basically same .